# UPDATE and CASE problem

Tags: postgresql, update, case, coalesce

It is my first question in this forum. 
I wrote this code, but it is incorrect and I can't find a problem.
I have 2 tables: `sciana (gid,id,geom)` and `sciana1(gid,id,geom)`. 
If table `sciana` is empty I want to `sciana.id = sciana.gid`, but if `sciana` is not null I want to find `max(sciana.id) + sciana1.gid`

```
UPDATE sciana1
SET id =
CASE
WHEN sciana.gid IS NULL THEN
    id = sciana1.gid
WHEN sciana.gid IS NOT NULL THEN
    (SELECT max(sciana.id)+sciana1.gid 
    FROM sciana )       
END;
```

First example:

```
`sciana` IS EMPTY, so after the update `sciana1` looks like

         1,1,geom1
         2,2,geom2
         ...
```

Second example:

`sciana` IS NOT EMPTY

```
         1,1,geom1,
         ...
         9,9,geom9
```

so after the update, `sciana1` contains

```
         1,10,geom10
         2,11,geom11
         ...
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to do. I suggest you add a few sample rows from both tables and what you want as a result (after the UPDATE). And also add the `CREATE TABLE` statements of both tables so we know datatypes and UNIQUE / PRIMARY KEY constraints.

Comment: Does the `sciana` table have only 1 (or 0) rows?

Comment: are you trying to set this field as IDENTITY column?

Comment: So, a table is never NULL (or NOT NULL).  It can be empty (or not empty).  NULL applies to values.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to do something like

```
UPDATE sciana1
   SET id = gid + COALESCE((SELECT max(id) FROM sciana), 0);
```

[`COALESCE()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) will return you the first non-NULL parameter.  Then `max(id)` is NULL for an empty table, which means the COALESCE expression returns 0 when the table is empty, and the actual maximum when it is not.

You can further improve this by checking if the value will be different after the update, thus sparing unnecessarily bloating the table:

```
UPDATE sciana1
   SET id = gid + COALESCE((SELECT max(id) FROM sciana), 0)
 WHERE id IS DISTINCT FROM gid + COALESCE((SELECT max(id) FROM sciana), 0);
```

[`IS DISTINCT FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html) is an operator that behaves similarly to `<>`, but also considers NULLs.  With a plain `<>` you might not get anything updated, as the comparison itself results in NULL (thus not matching any rows) if `sciana1.id` is empty.

One more important thing is that if `sciana` is big, an index on `id` can help a lot in finding its maximum.

And a last note: in the second `UPDATE` query, the `SELECT max()...` part is executed twice.  This can be prevented by moving it out to a CTE or a subquery like

```
UPDATE sciana1
   SET id = gid + COALESCE(m, 0)
  FROM (SELECT max(id) FROM sciana) AS t(m)
 WHERE id IS DISTINCT FROM gid + COALESCE(m, 0);
```

One should check which one results in a more efficient execution plan.  In my experiments, the latter produces a nested join, which with a higher number of rows in both tables gets slower than the first version, while being faster with low row numbers.

Comment: Thanks dezso and other. Coalesce it is what I'm looking for.